# Open location settings not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, location-services

I'm using this code to redirect to iOS settings for the location:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
}
```

But it is just redirecting to settings and not in location or bluetooth settings. Does anybody know if is any way to redirect to iOS location settings?

Thank you

Comment: user is now able to override our requestAlwaysAuthorization and downgrade it to requestWhenInUseAuthorization - Which means as a developer we now have to supply both descriptions in the Info.plist

 add a new key NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription

Comment: I have it already in my Info.plist file, but I think the problem is in this 'App-Prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES'

Comment: Have you checked this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424092/location-services-not-working-in-ios-11? 
it was useful for me previously when I have faced with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Declare `url` as:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"];
```

thus:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
}
```

---

**NOTE:**

The above approach should work for iOS 10.x and below (you could check: [How to programmatically open the WIFI settings in Objective-C on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126813/how-to-programmatically-open-the-wifi-settings-in-objective-c-on-ios-10)). However, the "app-prefs" URL scheme is *not* supported by Apple! prefs URLs are considered as private APIs, the only documented preference URL is the [`UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`](http://UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString). Obviously, is has nothing to do with the used programming language; Related:

- [Swift 4 - IOS 11 / “Apps-prefs=root” function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533748/swift-4-ios-11-apps-prefs-root-function-not-working)
- [IOS 11 / "Apps-prefs=root" function not working after update to Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487364/ios-11-apps-prefs-root-function-not-working-after-update-to-swift-3)

Roughly speaking, you are not able to do such a navigation anymore on iOS 11.

Comment: It looks same as with completionHandler, I think that 'App-Prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES' has been deprecated in iOS 10 and up, but I'm thinking if there is any other way.

Comment: @EgzonArifi So, based on my answer, trying to open the url leads you to the settings, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but with that it was planned to redirect to Settings>Privacy>Location Services. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopensettingsurlstring?language=objc). If your application uses location data or bluetooth you will see location and bluetooth settings there.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Click on project name >> target>> Info >> url Types >> URL Schemes.
For example you can see the screenshot.
[image]

Then use the code:

```
-(IBAction)openSettingViewToEnableLocationService:(id)sender
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
}
```